# Get Custom Options Dropdown list

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to retrieve the list of items in my custom options dropdown. Below is my item

[image]

Any idea how to retrieve these items? I want to place this into a select options. But tbh I don't know how to do this in Magento 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $option) {
    echo $option->getTitle();                  //get custom option title
    foreach ($o->getValues() as $value) {
        print_r($value->getData());            //get options list
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks